# Undo changes in SQL Server database since last restore

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

Let’s say I restore a database (say `db1`) from a backup (`backup1.bak`) and then modify a few tables in `db1`. At this point, if I want to go get rid of the changes and go back to the restored state, how can I do that? Currently, I am creating a new database (`db2`) from the same backup (`backup1.bak`) which is obviously not efficient. Can someone suggest how to undo just the changes in db1 since the last restore?

PS: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

After restoring your database, [create a database snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx).

To undo your changes, [revert your database back to your snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189281.aspx).

This will keep you from having to hold onto your .bak file... and if your database is large relative to the amount of changes you'll be making to your database, this can be more efficient.

Comment: Of course keep in mind that this is an Enterprise feature, so is only applicable in Dev, Enterprise, and Evaluation editions (and Data Center, but that edition has been retired as of SQL Server 2012).

Comment: Thanks! I'll go through the info in your links

Comment: Another thing to watch is, you cannot use database snapshots revert functionality if your database has any filetables/filegroups :( I learned this the hard way unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

To revert you can simply restore the database again from the backup `WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY`.